# Angular child routing problem with styles

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-routing, angular16

I am working with in a project with a backend and  front-end in Angular. I recieve the blog articles from the server, correctly but with the reload, angular not find a css stylessheet
[loadind correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wujq1.png)
It load correctly the blog article, but when i reload (press F5) the page, it appears the following error:
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/blog/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
[ERROR]

Here is my code from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McCYi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbnRW.png)

i dont know how to fix that, i think maybe is that i am working with async blogIDs that come from the server, but i dont know why at first it load correctly and when y press F5 then change

[before reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79LME.png)
[after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt8Wu.png)

Comment: `blog/styles` fall in your `blog/:id` route. In general the styles should be in the assets folder and, in index.html you have some like `<link src="assets/styles.css" el="stylesheet"/>`. (Angular copy your assets folder in the directory where you have the index.html) Are you using a base href different that `/` or `./`?

Comment: i have in angular.json, it is quite weird becasuse the styles in the app aworking, except in the blog/:id route. I have never experienced this issue before
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],

Comment: i am not adding a new styles file, just it not working whe i reload only in the path blog/id, in the other routes i can reload easily

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).